# Apache Solr filtering query contains "-" don't work

Tags: apache, solr, parameters, filtering

I have the problem with Apache Solr.

Into my result i have parameter named url.
It's returns some results, like this.

```
http://domain.com/re-RU/someLink
http://domain.com/de-DE/someLink
http://domain.com/en-EN/someLink
http://domain.com/cl-EN/someLink
http://domain.com/ka-EN/someLink
```

When i added a filtering query parameter to my query:

```
http://ip:port/solr/example/select?q=someSentence&fq=url:ru-RU&wt=json&indent=true
```

It's working very well, but only for `de-DE`, `ru-RU` landuages.

When i trying to filter something with `en-EN`, i getting result contains `cl-EN`, `ka-EN` too

Where is the problem?
How to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your schema.xml as your url might be broken on "-" like in en-EN,it might be creating tokens en and EN separately . For example, if you are using StandardTokenizerFactory as your tokenizer class, then en-EN will be broken as en and EN, de-DE into de and DE. Similarly when you are querying you need to check which tokenizer you should use while querying because if you are using StandardTokenizerFactory while querying then fq=en-EN will also be broken into tokens en and EN. For more about tokenizers, please check : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers

Comment: Thanks man!, I using the StandardTokeinzerFactory, but only what's i need to do is paste my filtering query parameter into " "

Answer (score 1):

Create an analyzer `urlFilter` in your `schema.xml` as below .

```
<fieldType name="urlFilter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1"generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowercaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

Then use above analyser as the `type` for your url field in `schema.xml` as below

```
<field name="url" type="urlFilter" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And then, query like this

```
http://ip:port/solr/example/select?q=someSentence&fq=url:*ru-RU*&wt=json&indent=true
```

This will 100% work . Let me know if that helps you :) .

Comment: It's a good idea, but I found faster. Only whats i need to do is paste my filtering query parameter into " ". &fq=url:"en-EN"

Comment: ya i read @skm answer , that's definitely better . Just was not aware of your schema settings .